# Add Google Analytics to track a button press

Tags: 7, google-analytics

I have the Google Analytics module installed with Drupal 7.  On a page, how would I track the press of a button with id "myButton".  There's a great example here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

but I'd like to learn how to leverage the GA module in Drupal 7 to do this.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [Google Analytics Event Tracking](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_et):

> Event Tracking is a way to track user interaction with out registering
>   a page view. Using Google Maps as an example site, event tracking
>   would allow the user to track Zoom, Drag, and View Change events
>   without contaminating the page view statistic.
>
> This module allows an interface for Google Analytics event tracking
>   capabilities. It provides a hook for other modules or "glue code" and
>   also has some handy drush commands.